# Can't find the issue: javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that gets called on the KeyDown event of a link.
Basically I'm trying to move down the table (the application calls it a ListBox).  In the first loop what I'm trying to do is see if they use the mouse to click inside the table first and my hope was to find the row value and then manipulate the class (highlight) from there.

Unfortunately right now I'm not even getting that far.  When the screen loads and I press the down button, the current row (0) has it's class changed as well as row (1).  But on the next down button press the tr_lst says it is undefined.  Which then throws the loop off and then I get all sorts of errors.

I tried to implement a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pXa4F/), however, I couldn't get it working.  But you can see some of the code I'm trying to implement.

```
function xKeyDown(event,ListBoxVal){


var tr_lst = $('#' + ListBoxVal).find('tr[class="LUGridRowHighlight"]');
var iCount = 0;

for (iCount = 0; iCount <= $('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr').length; iCount++){
    if($('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:eq('+iCount+')').attr('id') == tr_lst.attr('id')){
        lstRow = iCount;
        break;
    }
}


if (event.keyCode == 40){
//arrow down
    if(parseInt(lstRow) < $('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr').length)
    {
        if(parseInt(lstRow) == 0){
            document.getElementById(ListBoxVal).focus(); 
            lstRow +=1;

            document.getElementById($('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:eq('+parseInt(lstRow)+')').attr('id')).focus();
            $('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:eq('+parseInt(lstRow)+')').addClass('LUGridRowHighlight');
            $('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:eq('+parseInt(lstRow)+')').prev().removeClass('LUGridRowHighlight') .addClass('LUGridRow');
            
        }else{
            document.getElementById($('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:eq('+parseInt(lstRow)+')').attr('id')).focus();
            $('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:eq('+parseInt(lstRow)+')').addClass('LUGridRowHighlight');
            $('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:eq('+parseInt(lstRow)+')').prev().removeClass('LUGridRowHighlight') .addClass('LUGridRow');
            lstRow +=1;
        }
    }
...
```

**Update:**

After looking into this further...  It appears that when I click the down arrow more than once the following code is causing an error:

```
var tr_lst = $('#' + ListBoxVal).find('tr[class="LUGridRowHighlight"]');
```

When I try to print this out it is ***'undefined'***

I'm wondering since I am manipulating the class via jQuery do I need to add a .live somewhere to the find?  As I believe when elements are manipulated dynamically the .live comes into play.  Any suggestions?

Comment: are you really going to handle keydown event to scrooldown list, or you need to handle mousedown event ?

Comment: yes on the scrolldown list.  I'm operating off of requirements.

Comment: what i see on jsfiddle is that scrool works both up and down but your handler is not being called (Uncaught ReferenceError: xKeyDown is not defined) why do you need an additional handler for scrolling element with scroll bar in the first place ?

Comment: @vittore unfortunately I'm only able to give you some of the code in the fiddle.  You are right that the scrolling does work, my issue has to do with the for loop (I think)

Comment: reading your code and still can't figure out why. if you need just to scrool you do not need to do anything at all. otherwise what is the matter to handle keydown on particular listbox item, but not list box?

Comment: can you put one more time what you are trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: Basically I have 2 divs on the screen when the screen loads.  I want to set the focus on the 2nd div.  When I set the focus I am able to then scroll up and down the list using the keyboard.  When I just use the arrow keys everything works great!  The different rows get highlighted and unhighlighted.  However, what I also need to code for is when the user clicks into the div with the mouse and sets the row highlight at that time (not 0).  So the for loop is there to capture what element contains that class (to highlight).  And then I can move it around from there.  Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: @vittore let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2237/discussion-between-jeff-v-and-vittore)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function xKeyDown(event,ListBoxVal){

var $listBoxVal = $('#' + ListBoxVal);
var trs = $listBoxVal.find('tr');
var tr_lst = $listBoxVal.find('tr.LUGridRowHighlight');
var tr_lst_id = tr_lst.attr('id');
var iCount = 0;

for (iCount = 0; iCount <= trs.length; iCount++){
    if($listBoxVal.find('tr:eq('+iCount+')').attr('id') == tr_lst_id){
        lstRow = iCount;
        break;
    }
}


if (event.keyCode == 40){
//arrow down
    if(parseInt(lstRow) < $listBoxVal.find('tr').length)
    {
        if(parseInt(lstRow) == 0){
            $listBoxVal.focus(); 
            lstRow +=1;

            $("#"+$listBoxVal.find('tr:eq('+parseInt(lstRow)+')').attr('id')).focus();

           $listBoxVal.find('tr:eq('+parseInt(lstRow)+')').addClass('LUGridRowHighlight');

            $listBoxVal.find(' tr:eq('+parseInt(lstRow)+')').prev().removeClass('LUGridRowHighlight').addClass('LUGridRow');

        }else{
            $("#"+$listBoxVal.find('tr:eq('+parseInt(lstRow)+')').attr('id')).focus();
            $listBoxVal.find('tr:eq('+parseInt(lstRow)+')').addClass('LUGridRowHighlight');
            $listBoxVal.find('tr:eq('+parseInt(lstRow)+')').prev().removeClass('LUGridRowHighlight').addClass('LUGridRow');
            lstRow +=1;
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: I'd suggest (to both Shankar & Jeff V) changing the `for` statement to this, to improve performance and possibly reliability: `for(iCount = 0, iMax = $('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr').length; iCount <= iMax; iCount++)`

Comment: That didn't appear to work for me.  I think it has something to do with the .find as after the 1st click down I am manipulating the CSS and now it returns undefined (after the 1st click - which is successful).